# Filtering an inner ng-repeat , by an outer ng-repeat variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of items. Some of these items, are "child items" of some other "parent item". Instead of re-arranging the JSON from the server, i'm trying to just filter the results in the ng-repeat loop. Each item has an id and a "father_id" property. If this property has a value of 0, it means it's a father element. The problem is, that i didn't manage to filter the inner loop, which relies on the some value from the parent loop.

This is what i have in the parent loop, which works fine:

```
 ng-repeat="fatherEvent in pageInitialAjaxContent | filter:{father_id:0}"
```

This presents all elements whose "father_id" is 0, which means they do not have a parent element, which makes them parents themselves.

In the inner loop, i tried this, unsuccessfully:

```
ng-repeat="ChildEvent in pageInitialAjaxContent | filter:{father_id:fatherEvent.id}"
```

This is meant to filter the items, whose father ID corresponds the ID of the parent item. It gives me bizarrely unexpected results.

Can some one tell me what would be the proper way to construct this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to restructure the second ng-repeat like so

`ng-repeat="ChildEvent in pageInitialAjaxContent | filter:{father_id:fatherEvent.id}:true"`

The `:true` checks for an exact match whereas the default, `:false`, checks for a substring match.

Check out the `comparator` argument in the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: No, it didn't :-( I also tried various similar combinations

Comment: @sheff2k1 Have you tried `filter: {father_id: fatherEvent.id}` ? EDIT: Just saw your question edit and looks like you did.

Comment: Yes i have, and this was actually the original thing i've tried. What i wrote in the code example was a mistake on my part, and was since then corrected :D This syntax yield correct results in some of the parent items, and faulty in others....i have no clue how it's even possible

Comment: @sheff2k1 Try adding `:true` to the filter like my edited answer shows. That might fix the issue.

Comment: Awesome! I ran into that exact issue at one point. Seems like it should default to true not false.